# Planes intersecting x=-2 and y=3 in 3D

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

How can i get the parametric line equation for the planes $x=-2$ and $y=3$ in $3$D. Please provide the answer from the procedure by finding the normal vectors for both planes.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plane of equation $ax+by+cz=d$ is parallel to the plane $ax+by+cz=0$ that is $\langle(x,y,z)^T , (a,b,c)^T\rangle=0$ ( where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the scalar product), so the  vector $\vec u=(a,b,c)^T$ is normal to the plane.

In your case:

the normal vector to $x=-2$ is $ (1,0,0)^T=e_1$

the normal vector to $y=3$ is $ (0,1,0)^T=e_2$

so the vector directed as the common line is orthogonal to both these and is $e_3=(0,0,1)^T$ and the equation of the line is 
$$
(x,y,z)^T=t(0,0,1)^T+(-2,3,0)^T
$$

where $(-2,3,0)^T$ is a common point of the two planes.

Not that this can be found in a simpler way, noting the a point of the line **must** have $x=-2$, $y=3$ and can have any $z=t \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks.How can i find the perpendicular distance from P(2,0,6) to the line of intersection.

Comment: You can see : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wznbg_aKOo

Answer (score 0):

General case.
let $(a,b,c) $ be the normal vector to a plane and $(x_0,y_0,z_0 ) $ a point lying in that plane.

then we can take as vectors directors of the plane

$(-b,a,0) $  and  $(-c,0,a) $ to get the parametric equations

$$x=x_0-tb -uc$$
$$y=y_0+ta $$
$$z=z_0+ua $$.

In your case, for the first plane $x=-2$,
$(a,b,c )=(1,0,0) $
and
$(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(-2,0,0 ) $.